# Why is my question closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, questions

Recently, I posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4674255/solution-check-request-for-an-exercise-in-arbib-and-maness-showing-the-existenc) but end up being closed.  It states for the reason to be closed is that it is similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673761/solution-check-request-for-an-exercise-in-arbib-and-maness-showing-the-existenc).  The exercise cited in both posts clear indicated that it has two parts, and that I separated the exercise into two separate posts since the guidelines for asking good question on stackexchange is that I should try to ask one question per post.  I interpret that to mean if I was to ask a homework or exercise question that have multiple parts, I should focus on a single part per post.

Comment: If you think your post is wrongly closed as a duplicate, edit the closed post and clearly states why it is not a duplicate. Then regular users can vote to reopen your post. If it still does not work, post a request in the post that I linked above.

Comment: @ArcticChar I explicit stated that the questions are separated.  The exercise had two parts., also, if i did not, it would have made it confusing because I am quoting two separate theorems to two part solutions.

Comment: Your post is already reopened.

Comment: Regarding Questions that involve multiple part problems, you should (in the course of providing essential context) explain what relationship you know about between the parts of the problem.  For example, some such problems have a first part that is needed to solve the second part.  In other cases a second part asks for an example to illustrate the importance of the assumptions outlined in the first part.  As a rule of thumb there needs to be articulated justification for treating both parts of a problem together.

Comment: @ArcticChar thank you.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @hardmath ah kk.  I did not keep the two together even though the concepts of coequalizer and equalizer are dual concepts.  However, showing existence of one doesn't rely on having shown existence of the other part.

Comment: It sounds like a good idea to split them in such circumstance.  If you wind up posting first one and then the other, the second post can always include a link to the prior one (for context).

Comment: I believe some members moderate questions  (mark as duplicate especially) without  reading them